# Is it possible to make an entire img clickable even if it is overlapped by another element through z-index?

Tags: javascript, css, image

Here's my current situation: I have an image defined in `<img>` and a header defined in `<h3>`. However, because the part of the header was hidden behind the image, I set `z-index: 300` to the header in order to put it above the image. However, I also want to set `onClick` action to the image, so that when an user clicks on the image, he or she sees some sort of actions there. But since the header now covers the most of the image, the space that the user can tap to evoke the action is pretty small.

So I wonder whether it is still feasible to make the image fully clickable despite the fact that it is overlapped by another element. And I would like to know how to do it if it can be done in either CSS or JavaScript (or both).

I use HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: You could try making the image the background of a <div> element and then place the heading inside of it. Then you would not need the z-index and could set the onClick action on the <div>.

Comment: Also using `z-index: 2;` or something similar is way more readable and semantic than a value of 300, unless you already have 299 other z-index layers in your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can as well use pointer-events.

```
<header>
    <h1>My text overlapping</h1>
    <img class="fullSizeUnderneath"/>
</header>
```

and css :

```
header h1 {pointer-events:none;}
```

The mouse won't see it and image , even under it, will catch the click event. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pvfgD)**

Answer (score 2):

Don't attach the click event to the image.  Attach it to whatever wraps both the image and the h3.

```
<div class='parent'>
    <img />
    <h3></h3>
</div>
```

So you would bind to .parent in this example.

Comment: Then it makes not only the `img` but the entire `h3` clickable, right? I would like to make only the `img` clickable.

Comment: Then binding to the image will work as expected, from a design standpoint, unless you want the heading and the image to do different things, you _probably_ want the whole object to activate the same thing.